# Best way of managing View Controllers navigation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have the follow structure in my App:

When application first launches, it loads my initial view controller (**VC A**).
Then, it performs if user is logged in. If it's not, it presents another view controller (**VC B**).

From **VC B**, user logs in, and if it's an already registered user, it simply goes back to **VC A** (I call `dismiss` from **VC B**). If it's the first time the user logs in, then **VC B** calls a sequence of other view controllers, responsible for some kind of tutorial (say we have the sequence **VC T1**, **VC T2** and **VC T3**) one calling the other.

When **VC T3** is finished doing what it is supposed to do, it has to go back to **VC A**.

My question is how is the best way to do this.
Currently I am thinking of creating a segue back to the initial controller **VC A** directly from **VC T3**, but is there some kind of memory management problem on this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I believe is to use `UINavigationController` which has methods `popToViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)` and `popToRootViewController(animated: Bool)` among others

The view controller you need to pass to these methods you can instantiate from storyboard like this

```
var yourVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "youVCIdentifier")
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot to mention that in this case you should of course add UINavigationController to your storyboard:

`Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller`

Answer (score 1):

Better make this in AppDelegate

```
if userLogined {
  self.window?.rootViewController = loginedController
} else {
  self.window?.rootViewController = notLoginedController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to set your rootViewController from everywhere use it like:

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        let tabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    }
```